# VB.NET Error: "The ConnectionString property has not been initialized."

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

```
Dim Current As String
Current = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
con.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = " & Current & "\SchoolMaticsDatabase.mdb"
con.Open()
TabSelect()
con.Close()

Private Sub TabSelect()
        Select Case TabControl1.SelectedIndex
            Case Is = 0
                TabDay = "Monday"
            Case Is = 1
                TabDay = "Tuesday"
            Case Is = 2
                TabDay = "Wednesday"
            Case Is = 3
                TabDay = "Thursday"
            Case Is = 4
                TabDay = "Friday"
            Case Is = 5
                TabDay = "Saturday"
            Case Is = 6
                TabDay = "Sunday"
        End Select
        ds.Clear()
        sql = "SELECT [Forename],[Surname],[Subject Speciality 1],[Subject Speciality 2],[Subject Speciality 3],[Subject Speciality 4],[Subject Speciality 5],[Subject Speciality 6]," & StartTime & "," & EndTime & ",[Spec1],[Spec2],[Spec3],[Spec4],[Spec5],[Spec6] FROM [Staff] WHERE " & TabDay & " LIKE 'T'"
        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "SchoolMaticsDatabase")
End Sub
```

**da.fill(ds,"SchoolMaticsDatabase")>>> Errors occurs on this line of code.**

If tab index is changed the sub TabSelect() is called also. One other thing is that the program checks the day of the week and correctly displays the tab corresponding to that day. On Monday this code was working fine, as soon as it hit Tuesday this error cropped up.

Comment: The code snippet cannot compile as given.  Improve it and show inside what method the first 6 lines appear.  And show how you call this method.

Comment: Require more information to post an appropriate answer

Answer (score 0):

Try passing conn as a parameter into the TabSelect() function. `TabSelect(ByRef OleDbConnection conn)` It could be an issue of scope since you are playing with global variables

Comment: Thanks for the information. I tried passing the connection variable through the function but the same error is occurring.